# Java - Parsing TI-84 tokens into hex code

Tags: java, file-io, hex

Here's the problem:
I have a list of tokens that are valid tokens in the TI programming language. I am trying to write a program that will compile text that contains valid tokens into a TI-83/84 program, which is made up of entirely hexadecimal data. I know how to write the data into a file, and how to get the data from a file. 
I need to write a program to search through the program and identify valid tokens and be able to keep the order of the program. I've already thought of taking a token as a keyword and searching through the text like that, but the token that is first chosen is not always going to be the first in the text, so the order would be lost.

I've written my own Token Object and I'm using the following variables in my parser:

- ArrayList tokens - an ArrayList of Token objects (all the valid tokens of TI-BASIC)
- DataInputStream dis - also the text file
- String data - the text data that the program extracts from the file using a loadData method (not the problem, so not important how it works)
- DataOutputStream dos - the .8xp file to be written to

Token Class:

```
public class Token {

  private String tokenText;
  int[] hexValue;
  boolean isTwoByte;

  /**
   * The default constructor.
   * Assigns empty values to all instance variables.
   */
  public Token() {
    tokenText = "";
    hexValue = new int[0];
    isTwoByte = false;
  }

  /**
   * Constructs a Token with <tt>text</tt> text and an empty int[] for <tt>hexValue</tt>
   * @param text the text to be assigned to the Token
   */
  public Token(String text) {
    tokenText = text;
    hexValue = new int[0];
    isTwoByte = false;
  }

  /**
   * Constructs a Token with an empty String for <tt>text</tt> and <tt>hexValue</tt> value
   * This is a one-byte Token
   * @param value the value to be assigned to the Token
   */
  public Token(int value) {
    tokenText = "";
    hexValue = new int[1];
    hexValue[0] = value;
    isTwoByte = false;
  }

  /**
   * Constructs a Token with an empty String for <tt>text</tt> and <tt>hexValue></tt> v1v2
   * This is a two-byte Token
   * @param v1 the first byte of the two-byte value that will be assigned to the Token
   * @param v2 the second byte of the two-byte value
   */
  public Token(int v1, int v2) {
    tokenText = "";
    hexValue = new int[2];
    hexValue[0] = v1; hexValue[1] = v2;
    isTwoByte = true;        
  }

  /**
   * Constructs a Token with <tt>text</tt> text and <tt>hexValue</tt> value
   * This is a one-byte Token
   * @param text the text to be assigned to the Token
   * @param value the value to be assigned to the one-byte Token
   */
  public Token(String text, int value) {
    tokenText = text;
    hexValue = new int[1];
    hexValue[0] = value;
    isTwoByte = false;
  }

  /**
   * Constructs a Token with tokenText <tt>text</tt> text and <tt>hexValue</tt> v1v2
   * This is a two-byte Token
   * @param text the text to be assigned to the Token
   * @param v1 the first byte of the two-byte value that will be assigned to the Token
   * @param v2 the second byte of the two-byte value
   */
  public Token(String text, int v1, int v2) {
    tokenText = text;
    hexValue = new int[2];
    hexValue[0] = v1; hexValue[1] = v2;
    isTwoByte = true;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the text that is assigned to the particular Token
   * @return the text that is assigned to the particular Token
   */
  public String getText() {
    return tokenText;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the byte value of the Token
   * @return the byte value of the Token
   */
  public int[] getValue() {
    return hexValue;
  }

  /**
   * Returns <tt>true</tt> if the Token is a two-byte Token, and <tt>false</tt> otherwise
   * @return <tt>true</tt> if the Token is a two-byte Token, and <tt>false</tt> otherwise
   */
  public boolean isTwoByte() {
    return isTwoByte;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the tokenText text of the Token to the String passed it.
   * @param text the new text to be assigned to the Token
   */
  public void setText(String text) {
    tokenText = text;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the byte value of the Token to the integer passed it. This sets the isTwoByte variable to <tt>false</tt>.
   * @param value the new byte value to be assigned to the Token
   */
  public void setValue(int value) {
    hexValue = new int[1];
    hexValue[0] = value;
    isTwoByte =  false;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the byte value of the Token to the integers passed it. This sets the isTwoByte variable to <tt>true</tt>.
   * @param v1 value of the first byte of the two-byte Token
   * @param v2 value of the second byte
   */
  public void setValue(int v1, int v2) {
    hexValue = new int[2];
    hexValue[0] = v1; hexValue[1] = v2;
    isTwoByte = true;
  }
}
```

I hope that someone will be able to help me with this. If you need more information, such as any more code, that won't be a problem, the project will be open-source anyway. Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of what the input data might look like and what the output for that data set would be? Hopefully only a few lines for each would be needed.

Comment: The input data is be stored in a UTF-8 .txt file and look like this:

:TI-84 Prog
"Hello World"->Str1
Disp Str1:Stop

And the final output should be stored in a .8xp file which should contain the following raw hex data (not including the header):

3E 54 49 71 38 34 29 50 BBC2 BBBF BBB6 3F 2A 48 BBB4 BBBC BBBC BBBF 29 57 BBBF BBC2 BBBC BBB3 2A 04 AA00 3F DE AA00 3E D9

[:]=3E
["]=2A
[-]=71
[<space>]=29
[->]=
[Disp ]=DE
[Stop]=D9
[Str1]=predetermined variable with token value AA00
uppercase letters are the same as regular ASCII encoding
lowercase letters are two-byte tokens starting at BBB0

Comment: I apologize for the poor format of the info above, the comments won't allow new lines. There should be a newline after the "Prog" and after the first "Str1"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but does the `java.io.StreamTokenizer` class do what you need? Or, a simple `StringTokenizer` if you can read the source file in in its entirety.

Since you've be stepping through the file in order, you wouldn't need to worry about preserving order.

Comment: The StreamTokenizer looks promising. I use a BufferedReader to get the String data. But I've never used StreamTokenizer, so how would you use it to search for a certain token out of a prebuilt database?

Comment: I need to parse the source code linearly, if that helps to clarify. In any case, I need to keep track of where the hex values for the Token goes in the program. *How* I do that is not really important.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/672577/732379) will hopefully have some places to start as you're writing a compiler. Lots of links in that question.